# mobius transformation 2

Tags: mobius-transformation

I need a Möbius transformation from the set of  $z$s contained in the unit circle centered at the origin with real part greater than $0$ to
the infinite sector bounded by the lines making $45$ degrees with the real axis, i.e.  $$45^{^\circ}<\arg( z)<135^{\circ}.$$

So, I need to map three points but not sure if my choice is correct.

I need a map so that

$$i \to -1+i,-i \to 1+i, 1\to \infty.$$

Will these choices do?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone confirm my choice of points and images will be ok?

Comment: I think you made a mistake (but I am no expert) I guess you need $ i \to \infty $ $ -i \to 0 $ , $ 0 \to 1-i $ and $ 1 \to 1+i $ this is not the only option j or -j goes to 0 and the other to infinity

Comment: Can you explain why those values? I'm sure I found a thread on here asking for a map from a sector to unit circle.the answer to that was no mobius transformation existed so it had to be a conformal map then a mobius. Could this be the case here?

Comment: In your half circle at the points j and -j there is a right angle one of these angles you need at 0 and the other at infinity (far away) the others are to form the boundary rays